# django ajax request response

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views, ajax-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django file upload from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542739/django-file-upload-from-json)

Hi am using the following ajax upload from the template but i do not get a response from django view.What is wrong here..i do not see any alert

```
function ajax_upload(formid)
{
var form = $(formid);
form.ajaxSubmit({
  dataType:  'json',
  success:   function (data) {
  alert("Hereeeeeeee");
  if(data.status == '1')  
  {
     alert("Uploaded Successfull");
  }
  else 
  {
     alert("Uploaded UnSuccessfull :(");
  }
  }
} )   ; 
}
```

`EDIT`
Django:

```
  def someview(request):
      response_dict={'status':1}
      logging.debug("seen") //This is seen in the logs
      return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

`EDIT1`

Please also for complete source code look at [django file upload from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542739/django-file-upload-from-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
form.ajaxSubmit({
  dataType:  'json',
  success:   function (data) {
    alert("Hereeeeeeee");
```

Your callback executes on 'success', so we can narrow down the failure to the django view side. Assuming everything is syntactically correct, my best guess is that since you're returning json data, your response mimetype should be:

```
mimetype='application/json'.
```

If that doesn't work, I would suggest using Firebug on Firefox or Developer Tools on Chrome to look at the server response. You should be able to see a django stacktrace there.

Comment: I had tried this but i still do not see a response i can even do a render to response..Niot sure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Check that `someview` added to urls.py. 
Check that `{% csrf_token %}` added to form

Comment: Yes both are taken care of..If i put a log before return i do see it.Please see the edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

It's rather impossible you will see that log, hence this is a python syntax error:

```
response_dict{'status':1}
```

and should be:

```
response_dict = dict(status=1)
```

or:

```
response_dict = {'status':1}
```

or:

```
response_dict = dict()
response_dict['status'] = 1
```

or:

```
response_dict = dict()
response_dict.update({'status':1})
```

Comment: Oh sorry thats just a copy paste issue.I have edited the question